# getting empty parenthesis results in Django API when I created custom methods models -> Serializers -> Views

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am trying to fetch data from a function which is created in postgres sql in django rest framework but no luck. I have created a custom method in model and respective methods in serializer, views and urls. When I hit the api in the browser I am getting empty parenthesis{}.

For example if my function returns 10 records, I am getting 10 empty parenthesis in browser. Can you guys please help me to get the right data in the browser?
Thanks in advance.

I tried converting fetch.all() data to list but no luck.

**Models.py**

```py
    class Order(object):
        def get_order_details(): 
           with UseDatabase(GetConn.get_config()) as cursor: 
             cursor.execute('select * from public.fnorderdetails()')
             data = cursor.fetchall()
             return data
```

**Serializer.py**

```py
    class OrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):   
        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = ['o_code', 'o_type'] 

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Order.get_order_details()
```

**views.py**

```py
    class getOrderDetails(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 
        queryset = Order.get_order_details()
        serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```py
     path('getOrderDetails/', views.getOrderDetails.as_view()),
```

When I hit api in the browser, I get below results

```
    Result 
        **HTTP 200 OK
        Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
        Content-Type: application/json
        Vary: Accept**
        [
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {},
             {}
        ]
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting. The current formatting makes reading the content unnecessarily hard.

Comment: Hi Hagello, Formatted. Is this okay now? Thanks

Comment: Why is there parenthesis in your sql? `fnorderdetails()`?

Comment: parenthesis is important otherwise it throws error. I tired cursor.callproc('fnorderdetails') this too but no luck.

Comment: Guys, resolved it by changing the approach. Actually i have rewritten the logic using function based views.                                                        
 @api_view(['GET'])
 def order_detail(request):  
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = dict(Order.get_order_details())  
        return Response(queryset)

Comment: I think the problem is that the class `Order` is inherited from class `object`. In this case class `Order` should be inherited from `models.Model` or if inherited from `object` you should declare serializer `OrderSerializer` like here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers